# Import Multiple DBF files in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, dbf

I have 327 .DBF files that i need to import in **one** table in a database in Mircosoft SQL server. 
These files all have the exact same structures, and are in the same location. Each file contains between 10,000 and 120,000 records.

I have been told that the easiest way to do this is to automate a conversion of all files to .txt then create a batch to merge all .txt files then import using the wizard.

Is there a way i can write a SP or other to just import the DBF files directly?

If so would appreciate some help.

Thanks

Comment: **WHAT** concrete database are you talking about? `SQL` is just a query language - used by **many** database systems, and they all have different approaches on how to import foreign data. So please update your tags with the appropriate **database system** (and version) you're using - be it `MySQL`, `Postgres`, `SQL Server`, `Oracle`, `db2` or whatever else you might be using. ....

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DBF Commander Pro](http://dbf-software.com) for your task.

Open a DBF file, click File -> Export to DBMS. At the window appears Build the connection string and select the target table of the database to export data to. At the bottom of the window you'll see command line for the current export process:
[image: load DBF to database]

If you click on Export button then current DBF file will be exported to the database. But since you need to export 327 files, it's better to use a command line (BAT file) for this. So, you can create such BAT file, where every of DBF files will be exported with the command line you've got in a loop. E.g.:

```
dbfcommander.exe -edb "D:\Data\*some_filename*.dbf" destination_table "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;User ID=user1;Initial Catalog=test_db;Data Source=test_server"
```

More info on export process you can find [here](http://dbf-software.com/dbf-file.html#ImpExpDBMS). DBF Commander Pro using is described [here](http://dbf-software.com/dbf-command-line.html). The app has 20 days fully-featured trial period, so you can perform your task absolutely for free.

Comment: Thanks a tone Oleg, works perfectly. Didn't even take that long.